# Visual Studio Crawling when I type 'data-bind'

Tags: visual-studio, web-essentials

As soon as I start typing `data-bind` in VS 2013 (fresh install with web essentials and resharper), the IDE slows to a crawl (one character typed every 3 seconds).  I've applied the `knockout` registry fix to no avail.  It seems Web Essentials is causing this.  What can be done as a workaround (other than removing web essentials?)

Comment: maybe you need to keep only one extension ( either web essentials or reshaper) , it seems both together making troubles, I am using web essentials and no problem facing me as you mentioned

Comment: @HadiHassan If I didn't need both, I wouldn't be using both.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I think it started when I've installed resharper but I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not tried already , can you try this suggestion from [JetBrains web site](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.2/Speeding_Up_ReSharper.html)

> There are also reports on Web Essentials contributing to low
>   performance while editing .cshtml files. If you're affected by this
>   problem, consider going to Tools | Options | Web Essentials and
>   setting Auto-format HTML on Enter to False.

Comment: You know, this worked for one `data-bind` and then it didn't.  So I don't know how to handle this, but I'll remove the answer to hopefully attract more possible solutions.